# Grape API : Return Location header after a creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, grape-api

A POST request shall create the resource and return a "Location" header pointing to the created resource.

I'm using grape API with rails and asking myself what is the best way to return the created resource URI.
Is grape offering a way to get a resource URI without setting it manually ?

```
resource :blup do
  post '/' do
    blup = Blup.create(first_name: 'Jamie')
    if blup.present?
      header 'Location', 'HERE blup URI'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Try Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.blup_url blup.id

Answer (score 0):

For now I have not found anything better than this :

```
header 'Location', "#{request.url}/#{blup.id}"
```

But only work when request.url is the ressource root URI. (eg in a POST request)

Answer (score 0):

Though I do not know what Grape adds to Ruby on Rails API, I had the same problem, and I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40906575/8370072).
To give the location in a header after creation, you can add :

`render location: specific_thing_i_am_looking_for_url(@thing)`

And you can find specific_thing_i_am_looking_for_url by running

```
rake routes
```