# Rails 4 add location header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'd love to add location header in controller for the nested case.
I know how to add location header in Rails.

```
render json: json_body, status: 201, location: 'accounts'# :ok
```

However if the routing is nested, how can I deal with the case.

```
# routing
/api/v1/accounts/:account_id/subscriptions(.:format)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the named route helper methods to generate the correct location, ie:

```
render json: json_body, status: 201, location: subscriptions_account_url(@account)
```

Run `rake routes` to find the correct route name.